# How to control the fire rate of bullets?

Tags: python, pygame, python-2.6

I have been working for about 2-3 days just on how to control my fire rate and I just cannot find a successful way. I have seen similar/same questions on here but I did not find the answer I was looking for. In my game I have it so there is one player one bot, and its a 1v1 battle.

my bullet class:

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    change_y = 0
    list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([6,6])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.change_y = y

        Bullet.list.add(self)

    def update(self):

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

my activation/shooting action:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        if self.player.ammo > 0:
            self.shooting = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self.shooting = False

if self.shooting == True:

    self.bullet = Bullet(-45)
    self.bullet.rect.x = self.player.rect.x + 11
    self.bullet.rect.y = self.player.rect.y - 14
    Bullet.list.add(self.bullet)
    for bullet in Bullet.list:
        if self.player.ammo > 0:
             self.player.ammo -= 1
```

I am fairly new still. I have tried many different ways, some extremely silly ways. I can give you more code if you need it. Any help is awesome, to be clear I want my bullets to have an increased time in between shots because as of now it shoots 60 bullets/second. Also while Im here I may as well ask for help with reloading too because right now all I have is

```
if self.player.ammo == 0:
        self.shooting = False
        self.player.ammo = 30
```

Comment: Use 4-space indentation, consistently, please. Otherwise it's no fun looking at your code.

Comment: You should accept my edit for Pygame tag.

Comment: sorry that happens when i c/p and i actually i fixed that right when i saw that xD

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the time between shots.

For example:

```
if self.shooting == True:
  if time.Time() - self.last_shot > self.shot_delay:
    self.bullet = Bullet(-45)
    self.bullet.rect.x = self.player.rect.x + 11
    self.bullet.rect.y = self.player.rect.y - 14
    Bullet.list.add(self.bullet)
    self.last_shot = time.Time()
    for bullet in Bullet.list:
      if self.player.ammo > 0:
      self.player.ammo -= 1
```

Where `self.shot_delay` is the delay you want.

Comment: could you please add more description? this code does nothing but raises more questions and confusion.

Comment: All it does is measure the time between your last shot, `self.last_shot` and now `time.Time()` to see if it is greater than the delay, `self.shot_delay` you want between firing bullets.

`time.Time()` returns a number of seconds.